# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in xampp / wamp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, wamp, wampserver

I have same problem in xampp and wamp, i didn't have any password for user root also when i assign some password to user root then phpmyadmin said

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I am confuse how to fix this problem

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try just root as a username?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to run the grant command at mysql

GRANT ALL on *.* to  'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '' WITH GRANT OPTION;

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for my case, i have two instance of MYSQL running on my machine so i just uninstall once then its work fine, no error again